# image handling in iphone / ipad app

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, ipad

When creating an app that will run on iPad and iPhone, how does the image management work?

Say you have an app that was created for the iPad and all of the background images are 1024x748 ( I know thats not retina size).

If you were to make this app also run on the iPhone you wouldnt want people to have to download the full 1024x748 backgrounds with the iPhone version.

I understand that you can supply images for each device but does apple somehow set up the app so that if you download the iPhone version it doesnt download the larger pictures?

Or am I misunderstanding something entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to options:

1. create an universal app where all the graphics will be inside
2. create 2 separate apps and in the iphone add only iphone graphics and in the ipad add only ipad graphics.

Comment: Gothcha, I kinda inferred that from Eimantas' answer but that clears it up for sure. I guess I had it in my head that apple would get the code and create 2 binaries, one for the ipad and one for the iphone. Thanks for setting me straight!

Answer (score 2):

All default splash images have to be shipped with the app. iPad and iPhone versions if the app is universal. They must have ~ipad and ~iphone suffixes accordingly. You can't tell Apple - "hey, exclude 1024x768 images because the dude is using an iPhone". The Application bundle is signed by you and by apple. Tweaking it post-submission will cause it to be invalidated.

Comment: By default splash images I think your talking about the loading screen images? And I assume thats how it is for all the images in the app? So if you had an image heavy app it would make more sense to have separate ipad and iphone apps with the images supplied in the iphone version having been re-sized to smaller images?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense, because now you have 50MB limit when downloading the application as well as your apps' ratings would suffer if you created two separate apps. However it would make sense to make images "universal" as in be fit for iPhone and iPad UI (except for loading images).